# PCC-F-02102, Fatal error while doing C preprocessing AIX 5.3

Tags: c++, c, oracle

```
Oracle version - 10.2.0.1.0
Pro*C/C++: Release 10.2.0.1.0
AIX version -  5.3
```

I cannot compile with the following errors.

```
Syntax error at line 135, column 2, file /usr/include/standards.h:
Error at line 135, column 2 in file /usr/include/standards.h
#warning  The -qdfp option is required to process DFP code in headers.
.1
PCC-S-02014, Encountered the symbol "warning" when expecting one of the following:

   a numeric constant, newline, define, elif, else, endif,
   error, if, ifdef, ifndef, include, line, pragma, undef,
   an immediate preprocessor command, a C token,
The symbol "newline," was substituted for "warning" to continue.

Syntax error at line 382, column 3, file mydb.h:
Error at line 382, column 3 in file mydb.h
  time_t timestamp;  
..1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "time_t" when expecting one of the following
:

   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,
The symbol "enum," was substituted for "time_t" to continue.

Error at line 0, column 0 in file my_db.pc
PCC-F-02102, Fatal error while doing C preprocessing
make: *** [libdb.a] Error 1
```

Any solution?

### pcscfg.cfg

```
sys_include=(/usr/include)

CODE=ANSI_C
parse=partial
sqlcheck=full
sys_include=/usr/include
sys_include=/usr/include/sys
sys_include=/usr/include/linux
include=$(ORACLE_HOME)/precomp/public
include=$(ORACLE_HOME)/precomp/include
include=$(ORACLE_HOME)/oracore/include
include=$(ORACLE_HOME)/oracore/public
include=$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/include
include=$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/public
include=$(ORACLE_HOME)/rdbms/demo

ltype=short
define=__64BIT__
define=_IBM_C
define=_LONG_LONG
```

The exactly same code is fine in AIX 5.2. The problem is occurred in AIX 5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error reported, PCC-S-02014, is actually the important one. The Pro*C precompiler ignores some C preprocessor directives, but not `#warning` - it doesn't understand it, and doesn't think `warning` is a valid thing to have after a `#`.

You can use the `ORA_PROC` macro to avoid problematic header files being included at this stage. Assuming the location given in a previous answer is right, you can 'hide' the `#include` from the preprocessor like this:

```
#ifndef ORA_PROC
#include <standards.h>
#endif
```

Of course you may not be including that file directly, so you might have to work out the heirarchy to see which file you really need to exclude in your source file. In your case it looks like you could maybe hide `mydb.h` within your `my_db.pc` file, but that seems excessive; it might be better to hide `standard.h` within your `mydb.h` file - basically exclude the minimum amount of code you can. I'm speculating from the error messages though, you may have more layers.

This is covered in the [advanced topics](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_05adv.htm) section of the Pro*C/C++ documentation.

This is easier than copying and editing the system header file, and much safer than editing the original. It also allows you to add comments explaining what's happening, of course.

Comment: The problem was I could not find which file included "standards.h". The library was quite complex and written by another person.

Comment: @Lwin Htoo Ko: You can find which file(s) include `standards.h` with the C preprocessor: `$ cpp -H  my_db.pc >/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually occurred in AIX 5.3 and above. The /usr/include/standards.h is different from older version and I think PCC is somehow not able to compile.

To fix that issue, you have to change the followings in standards.h.

```
FROM
---

#if defined(__IBM_PP_WARNING)
#warning  The -qdfp option is required to process DFP code in headers.
#else
#error  The -qdfp option is required to process DFP code in headers.

TO
--

//#if defined(__IBM_PP_WARNING)
//#warning  The -qdfp option is required to process DFP code in headers.
//#else
#if !defined(__IBM_PP_WARNING)
#error  The -qdfp option is required to process DFP code in headers.
```

I suggest not to change the system include file. So, copy `standards.h` file into your project directory, fix and use it.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to copy a system include file into your project.  I suggest you reconsider [Alex Poole](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711541/1438)'s answer.

Comment: I cannot exclude standards.h because my program needs it.

Comment: But Pro*C probably doesn't need `standards.h`.  The beauty of using `#ifndef ORA_PROC` is that it hides whatever you put after it from the precompiler but not the C compiler.  In any case, the maintenance cost of having a custom "standard" system include file for your project just isn't worthwhile.  This is bad advise for people who, like myself, find the answer via Google.

Comment: You may safely delete this part from /usr/include/standards.h, it doesn't actually make any sense anyways.